# Advice on how to minimize taxes when selling US stock

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, canada, non-resident

I live in Canada and own US stock, I have filled W8 form and it says that the account is W8 Ben certified. I sold already some shares and was surprised that I paid 15% taxes on total amount? I thought I would only have to pay taxes if there is capital gain.

Comment: Something isn't right.  Call your broker and have it explained.  There is only 15% withholding on dividends (30% without a W8).  There's no withholding on capital gains for stocks.  What kind of stock was it, there may be some exceptions?

Comment: What country is your brokerage account in? How did you acquire the stock? Is it a special kind of account?

Comment: I'm in the US and when I receive distributions from a Canadian company I own there's a 15% withholding.  When I file my taxes the withholding is indicated on the various forms I receive from my broker and is deductible.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't pay any taxes. What happened was that an amount (15%) was withheld by the broker, as required by the US law, towards any potential tax liabilities that you may have. If the amount withheld was more than the actual tax you owe - you'll get a refund when you file your tax return.

The reason for the mandatory withholding is that since you're a foreigner there's no other way to force you file a tax return. And the rate is set high enough (15% of the distribution) to ensure that all the potential tax is captured.

This is not US-specific, similar rules exist in almost any country. I would assume Canada has them as well.

Comment: hi, thank you for answering my question, so I could get it back at the end of the year? I would have to file my taxes with in US?